# replace content of a div with clicked div content using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, replacewith

I am struggling with this one, I hope some one can help.

What I'm trying to achieve is on the click of a div, replace that div by another, so if I have

```
<div class="nibbles"><img src="something"/><h1>Something</h1><p>something</p></div>
<div class="nibbles"><img src="something"/><h1>Something</h1><p>something</p></div>
<div class="nibbles"><img src="something"/><h1>Something</h1><p>something</p></div>
<div class="nibbles"><img src="something"/><h1>Something</h1><p>something</p>
```

If I click any of these divs, that div should be replaced by below div

```
<div class="picked_nibble"></div>
```

And if I click another `.nibble div` the `.picked_nibble` will swap for that content. I have tried lots of combinations with `.html` and `.replaceWith` but cant get it to work? See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/nhnw6bgg/1/)

If I can eventually get this to work I would like to have a fade animation when the content appears or is replaced and also have the `h1` content added into a form input for submitting later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code. with fadeIn effect . check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nhnw6bgg/8/)

UPDATE  : save h6 value to textbox

```
 $('.nibble_pick').click(function() {
   $('.nibble_choice').hide().html( $( this ).html()).fadeIn('slow');
   $('#title').val( $(this).find('h6').html() );
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.nibbles').click(function(){
    var innerContent = $(this).html();
    $('div.picked_nibble').hide().html(innerContent).fadeIn('slow');
    $('#input').val( $(this).find('h1').text() );
});
```

Comment: brilliant! thanks, how could I combine this with getting the h1 content into the from field?

Comment: sorry, dont understand?

Comment: @JonJones how do you want to add `h1` to a form? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @zack sorry fro not being clear, I dont need the h1 just the content within, exactly like Wio's solution above but with your fade